# Python - Population of PANDAS dataframe column based on conditions met in other dataframes' columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, custom-function

I have 3 dataframes (df1, df2, df3) which are identically structured (# and labels of rows/columns), but populated with different values.

I want to populate df3 based on values in the associated column/rows in df1 and df2. I'm doing this with a FOR loop and a custom function:

```
for x in range(len(df3.columns)):
    df3.iloc[:, x] = customFunction(x)
```

I want to populate df3 using this custom IF/ELSE function:

```
def customFunction(y):
    if df1.iloc[:,y] <> 1 and df2.iloc[:,y] = 0:
        return "NEW"
    elif df2.iloc[:,y] = 2:
        return "OLD"
    else:
        return "NEITHER"
```

I understand why I get an error message when i run this, but i can't figure out how to apply this function to a series. I could do it row by row with more complex code but i'm hoping there's a more efficient solution? I fear my approach is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v1 = df1.values
v2 = df2.values

df3.loc[:] = np.where(
    (v1 != 1) & (v2 == 0), 'NEW',
    np.where(v2 == 2, 'OLD', 'NEITHER'))
```

Comment: YES! This is awesome and so simple. Thanks piRSquared, this knowledge is going to be a real asset for me moving forward!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, try to avoid loops in pandas, its inefficient and built to be used with the underlying numpy vectorization.

You want to use the apply function.

Something like:

```
df3['new_col'] = df3.apply(lambda x: customFunction(x))
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Thanks tormond, though the error i'm getting is with the custom function, as i'm trying to use conditions on a series. Here's the error message:

"ValueError: ('The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: So this is answered in plenty of places.                                                               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: I might be missing what your're trying to tell me, but that thread deals with filtering a dataframe using columns from the same dataframe. I'm trying to use conditions to populate a complete column using values from other dataframes.

Comment: The problem is with the conditional.  From the first sentence of that answer "The or and and python statements require truth-values. For pandas these are considered ambiguous so you should use "bitwise" | (or) or & (and) operations"